# Need to remove a piece of copy that appears to be in a sidebar but doesn't show up

Tags: widgets

I cannot find the type shown in these 2 screen grabs. 
Can anyone point me to where I can access and remove it?
[html code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1tKh.png)
[image: Type to be removed]

Comment: What kind of page is this shown on? Single Post, single Page, Category, Homepage, ...?

Comment: Apparently it is in your theme's `sidebar.php` file.

Comment: in your widgets?